# Print the input box text as simple text instead of html tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have used a Wordpress theme and customiser text print as html tag. I want to print as text like.

```
<a href="tel:704-372-6846">704 372 6846</a>
```

I want to display the "704 372 6846" text with link as we get in the frontend.

I am trying strip_tags() for this. But it is still not working. Where I am doing wrong.

Comment: This is the same problem https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190226/html-output-via-theme-customizer-is-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php). It decodes the html tags and shows the text as it is.

**According to its documentation:**

html_entity_decode — Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters

So in you case use it like this

```
<?php
$phone = html_entity_decode("<a href='tel:704-372-6846'>704 372 6846</a>
");
echo $phone;
```

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that You saved the text as HTML format (input) but you want to print it as a link in front end, If this is your question

Then a quick solution for this is to use CSS and JavaScript to hide the text box and show it as Archer tag.

Check for my demo
http://cssdeck.com/labs/imxsreqk

HTML

```
<div class="inputContainer">
    <input class="myInput" type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput" value="704 372 6846" />
    <a href="#" id="inputAncher"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inputContainer {
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
}
.inputContainer input {
  display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
(function () {
  var inputval = document.getElementById('myInput').value;
  var ancher = document.getElementById('inputAncher');
  ancher.innerHTML = inputval;
})();
```